# client-side vs server-side

Tags: php, javascript, database

In general, should one design in order to place processing load on client-side?

More specifically, a search engine to locate subscriber information requires a fair amount of parsing (multiple phone numbers to sort and format, hour of day, timezone, comparisons for possible substitutions of user information, etc.).

Again, in general, is it preferred that one have client-side do the work?

It seems to me 'yes' in a situation in which one will have many thousands of hits per minute.

Use php for quick database queries ... process retrieved data client-side.

yes ... no?

Answer (score 2):

No. I think a website should be able to work without Javascript at all. Client side scripting is for adding extra usability and graphical features.

For a web application targeted to a specific user group that's a different case, but for generic websites, don't do that stuff on the client, or implement it for both, so it will be done by the server when the client cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many variables at play. If you want guaranteed results you'd want it all server-side.

You never know if someone will be viewing your site in a text browser (lynx) or without JS turned on.

A better answer would be to cache pages wherever possible, or segments of pages to prevent the whole thing being re-built on each request. And, of course, optimising your code where possible.

Answer (score 0):

GolezTrol's answer is great. I just want to add one more thing - security reason. One principle of designing a secure website is never exposing underlying data structure to the users.

So if you deliver the raw data to the client side, any user with some fair amount of technical skills can see your exact data structure, and have much better insight to how your website work hence a better chance to hack your site.